# How can I include sitemap breadcrumb in my Tridion page?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I used to write

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" Runat="server" />
```

in my .net application to show the navigation *site map* breadcrumb. Can anyone please tell me how to use this type of functionality in Tridion page? Or should I use this as a user control and add it to my page?

And one more thing as you see *download PDF* link in the image. How can I link this text to my respective PDF file placed in building block folder? Should I write tcm id of the file(multimedia component) like this?

```
<a href="tcm id of file" > Download PDF </a>
```

Would this be the correct approach?

[image]

Comment: There are two separate and unrelated questions in here. I suggest you split it into two questions to make sure that people can answer them separately. For future reference: if you find yourself typing "one more thing" or "also", consider if you aren't combining separate questions into one.

Comment: sure frank, i'll take care of that in future. thanx for ur suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, you have 2 questions in here - these should really be 2 separate questions. Moving on.

There's nothing stopping you from using `<asp:SiteMapPath>` from a website that uses Tridion - as long as you have a SiteMap provider and you create the required navigation.sitemap (or whatever .NET calls it).

Alternatively, you could create your breadcrumb at publish time by determining the location of your page in the website like I explain in [this](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/01/its-little-things-creating-page.html) post.

For your pdf download, yes, you should have a template in Tridion generating those `<a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@"><img src="images/pdf.png" /></a>` or something like that. Don't go hard-coding your TCM Uris please.

Comment: You will need to add tridion:type="multimedia" to the link as well in order to link to the PDF I think

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this article that explains how to publish a Sitemap data source XML from Tridion. You can then use it with standard .net navigation user controls.:
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/web-sitemap